# cannot resolve class error in jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

jenkins pipeline

```
@Library('shared_lib') _
def util =new Utility('amr')
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps {
            echo 'Hello ' + util.name
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**src/com/rifi/Utility.groovy**

```
package com.rifi
Class Utility{
def name
Utility(_name){
    this.name=_name
 }
}
```

**WorkflowScript: 2: unable to resolve class Utility
@ line 2, column 11.
def util =new Utility('amr')**

Comment: hmmm `import com.rifi.Utility` or `def util = new com.rifi.Utility('amr')`

Answer (score 0):

first when using src it must be scriptive not declarative so i change pipeline to
**node {}**
**it works**
but i need to use declarative so i change to vars make some functions that return the
class
in pipeline i called